# Como fazer para uma paginação dinâmica executar a mesma função a qual foi renderizada?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou renderizando dinamicamente uma `view` com a paginação definida e para realizar esta ação eu utilizo a seguinte função:

```
$('#form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const request = $.ajax({
        url: '/module/controller/action',
        method: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });

    request.done(function (data) {
        $('#dynamic_elements').html(data);
    });
});
```

Eu gostaria que a paginação executasse a mesma função enviando o número da página através do método `GET` para a mesma `controller` que é usada para renderização da `view` via `POST`.

Segue o exemplo da paginação:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="active"><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Você carrega a página através da submissão de um formulário? Que formulário seria esse e qual a relação dele com a paginação?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, É carregada a `view` após a submissão do formulário. Esse formulário fornece parâmetros que são utilizados para filtrar a query no banco de dados. Como podem existir de 0 a mais de 100K de registros, a minha controller cria a páginação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie um *event handler* para os links que não estão dentro da `<li>` com a classe `.active`, disparando um *trigger* para o evento `.submit` do form, passando um parâmetro com o número do botão:

```
$(".pagination a").on("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   if(!$(this).parent().hasClass("active")) $('#form').trigger("submit", $(this).text().trim());
});
```

O `if` acima irá impedir que o link que estiver dentro da `li` com a classe `.active` dispare o trigger. Talvez a página ativa não interessa ser recarregada, mas se quiser que fique habilitada para o clique também, basta remover o `if`:

```
$(".pagination a").on("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#form').trigger("submit", $(this).text().trim());
});
```

Note que o trigger envia como parâmetro para  evento `.submit` o texto do link, então é preciso colocar na função do evento `.submit` uma segunda variável para receber essa informação:

```
$('#form').submit(function (e, v) {
                               ↑
```

Agora basta concatenar na URL do controller o parâmetro da página que será enviada via GET:

```
url: '/module/controller/action'+ (v ? '?pagina='+ v : ''),
```

O operador ternário irá verificar se a variável `v` tem algum valor e concatenar na URL do controller o parâmetro `?pagina=` mais o valor em `v` (no lugar de `pagina` você usa o nome que achar melhor).

No controller você irá receber o valor em `pagina` com `$_GET['pagina'];`. O formulário em si você irá receber normal com `$_POST`.

---

Se os links da paginação estiverem sendo criados na página após o carregamento da mesma, altere o *event handler* para a forma abaixo (forma delegada):

```
$(document).on("click", ".pagination a", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#form').trigger("submit", $(this).text().trim());
});
```

Comment: Excelente resposta, funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado por disponibilizar o seu tempo para nos ajudar!

Comment: Sam, deixa eu te perguntar uma coisa. No caso, essas paginações são renderizadas em um `panel` do bootstrap. Caso em meu formulário eu selecione mais de um usuário, são renderizados um `panel` para cada usuário selecionado. Como limitar a requisição da página somente para o `panel` em que foi clicado? É muito complexo a solução?

Comment: Quando tem mais de um panel são feitas mais de uma requisição?

Comment: Somente a requisição que postei. Na view existe um loop onde crio os painéis para cada usuário selecionado. O ideal seria uma request para cada um?

Comment: Cara, não consegui visualizar a questão. Quando clicar na paginação atualizar apenas o panel onde foi clicado o número da página?

Comment: Exato, pois podem ser renderizados mais de um painel. Só que a renderização é feita através de uma única função (postada acima). Se, por exemplo, são gerados três painéis e eu quero trocar a página apenas do segundo painél vai ser preciso uma outra função ou consigo utilizar a mesma?

Comment: Veja que o resultado do Ajax vai para o elemento `$('#dynamic_elements')`. Se vc tiver, por exemplo, 3 panel, vai ter 3 `$('#dynamic_elements')`? Se for isso, está incorreto pq não pode repetir id's, se é que entendi.